# Agrupar conteúdo por mês

Tags: php

Boa tarde pessoal, preciso agrupar uma lista pelo mês, utilizo o campo do tipo date na tabela. Tentei fazer, mas ele repete o mês a cada tinha da lista. Vejam meu código.

```html
$dados = Connection::select("SELECT *,date_format(`data`,'%d/%m/%y') as `data_formatada`, date_format(`data`,'%M') as mes FROM `noticias` where mes =' . $mes . '");
                   
                    
                   
                    $tbody = '';
                    
                    foreach ($dados as $reg) {

                        $tbody .= 
                                '
                                <thead>' . $reg['mes'] . '</thead>
                                <div class="medium-3 columns">
                                    <img src="' . $reg['imagem'] . '" width="155px" class="thumbnail" title="' . $reg['titulo'] . '"></img>
                                </div>
                                <div class="medium-9 columns">
                                    <a style="color: #008000;" href="' . URL . 'noticias/exibir-id/' . $reg['id'] . '">' . $reg['titulo'] . '</a><br>
                                    <small class="subheader">Por:<b> ' . $reg['por'] . '</b><br>Data: ' . $reg['data_formatada'] . '</small><br>
                                    <small class="subheader">' . $reg['titulo'] . '</small>
                                </div><hr>
                                    ';
                    }

                    $html = str_replace('#TBODY#', $tbody, $html);
                   

                    

                    return $html;
                    break;
```

Vejam a imagem abaixo como ela fica. Se alguém puder ajudar.

[image]

Gostaria que ficasse assim:

[image]

Comment: Ok. Temos o resultado atual. Mas qual resultado deseja?

Comment: Que agrupe por mês. Exemplo: 
<br>
Feveiro
Noticia 01
Data: 01/02/2016
Noticia 02
Data: 02/02/2016
Noticia 03
Data: 03/03/2016

Comment: Uma opção seria você colocar o título do Mês antes do loop. A outra opção seria criar uma variável antes do loop chamada $mes_atual, daí dentro do loop você faz uma verificação se $mes_atual é diferente de $reg['mes'], caso seja diferente, daí imprime o $reg['mes'], caso seja igual ele não repetirá. É fácil, mas se ainda tiver dúvida, me fala que monto pra você

Comment: outra coisa, já aproveitando pra palpitar no código, semanticamente o <thead> é um elemento pra ser usado dentro de uma <table>

Comment: Entendi, vou tentar aqui. Sobre o <thead> a tag <table> está dentro do html. (executando por uma view). Dai eu executo um load. 

$html_noticias= new Html();
$html = $html_noticias->load('view/noticias/show.html');
                    
                    $tmes = '';
                    $tbody = '';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deixei comentado onde fiz as alterações.

Segue:

```
$dados = Connection::select("SELECT *,date_format(`data`,'%d/%m/%y') as `data_formatada`, date_format(`data`,'%M') as mes FROM `noticias` where mes =' . $mes . '");



                $tbody = '';

                $mes_atual = ''; // <======== ADICIONADO

                foreach ($dados as $reg) {

                    // ==== ADICIONADO ==========
                    if ( $mes_atual != $reg['mes'] ) {
                        $tbody .= '<thead>' . $reg['mes'] . '</thead>';
                        $mes_atual = $reg['mes'];
                    }
                    // ==========================


                    // Do $tbody foi removido o <thead>
                    $tbody .= 
                            '
                            <div class="medium-3 columns">
                                <img src="' . $reg['imagem'] . '" width="155px" class="thumbnail" title="' . $reg['titulo'] . '"></img>
                            </div>
                            <div class="medium-9 columns">
                                <a style="color: #008000;" href="' . URL . 'noticias/exibir-id/' . $reg['id'] . '">' . $reg['titulo'] . '</a><br>
                                <small class="subheader">Por:<b> ' . $reg['por'] . '</b><br>Data: ' . $reg['data_formatada'] . '</small><br>
                                <small class="subheader">' . $reg['titulo'] . '</small>
                            </div><hr>
                                ';
                }

                $html = str_replace('#TBODY#', $tbody, $html);




                return $html;
                break;
```

Comment: Exatamente isso cara. Muito obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Faz primeiro um foreach na consulta do banco e guarda em um array:

```
foreach ($dados as $reg) {
    $arrayDoBanco = $reg['mes'][] = $reg;
}
var_dump($arrayDoBanco);
```

Depois faz um foreach para exibir dos dados:

```
foreach ($arrayDoBanco as $mes => $reg) {
  echo "<div>".$mes."</div>";
  //...
}
```

Você também pode simplificar seu select assim usando a funcao month para as colunas datetime ou timestamp:

```
("SELECT *,month(`data`) as mes FROM `noticias` where mes =' . $mes . '");
```

Comment: Vou testar. Obrigado.